# Is it possible to get the list of coauthors via office JS API?

Tags: javascript, office365, add-in

Although I'm trying to get the list of authors of a shared document using the Office JS API,I'm still open to any other tools or API in order to do so? this is an O365 related question.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out the answer was One Drive API. Man, these APIs are super rich and cool!